# Is it possible to do this type of search in Java

Tags: java, file-io, bigdata

I am stuck on a project at work that I do not think is really possible and I am wondering if someone can confirm my belief that it isn't possible or at least give me new options to look at.

We are doing a project for a client that involved a mass download of files from a server (easily did with ftp4j and document name list), but now we need to sort through the data from the server. The client is doing work in Contracts and wants us to pull out relevant information such as: Licensor, Licensee, Product, Agreement date, termination date, royalties, restrictions.

Since the documents are completely unstandardized, is that even possible to do? I can imagine loading in the files and searching it but I would have no idea how to pull out information from a paragraph such as the licensor and restrictions on the agreement. These are not hashes but instead are just long contracts. Even if I were to search for 'Licensor' it will come up in the document multiple times. The documents aren't even in a consistent file format. Some are PDF, some are text, some are html, and I've even seen some that were as bad as being a scanned image in a pdf.

My boss keeps pushing for me to work on this project but I feel as if I am out of options. I primarily do web and mobile so big data is really not my strong area. Does this sound possible to do in a reasonable amount of time? (We're talking about at the very minimum 1000 documents). I have been working on this in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache tika can extract plain text from almost any commonly used file format.

But with the situation you describe, you would still need to analyze the text as in "natural language recognition". Thats a field where; despite *some* advances have been made (by dedicated research *teams*, spending many person years!); computers still fail pretty bad (heck even humans fail at it, sometimes).

With the number of documents you mentioned (1000's), hire a temp worker and have them sorted/tagged by human brain power. It will be cheaper and you will have less misclassifications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I chose yours because my main question was is it possible and you answered that part the best.

Answer (score 2):

I'll do my best to give you some information, as this is not my area of expertise. I would highly consider writing a script that identifies the type of file you are dealing with, and then calls the appropriate parsing methods to handle what you are looking for.

Since you are dealing with big data, python could be pretty useful. Javascript would be my next choice.

If your overall code is written in Java, it should be very portable and flexible no matter which one you choose. Using a regex or a specific string search would be a good way to approach this;

If you are concerned only with Licensor followed by a name, you could identify the format of that particular instance and search for something similar using the regex you create. This can be extrapolated to other instances of searching.

---

**For getting text from an image, try using the API's on this page:**

- [How to read images using Java API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199275/how-to-read-images-using-java-api)
- [Scanned Image to Readable Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903345/scanned-image-to-readable-text)

---

**For text from a PDF:**

- https://www.idrsolutions.com/how-to-search-a-pdf-file-for-text/
- Also, PDF is just text, so you should be able to search through it using a regex most likely. That would be my method of attack, or possibly using string.split() and make a string buffer that you can append to.

---

**For text from HTML doc:**

- Here is a cool HTML parser library: http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html
- A resource that teaches how to remove HTML tags and get the good stuff: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0424.html

---

If you need anything else, let me know. I'll do my best to find it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use tika for text extraction. If there is a fixed pattern, you can extract information using regex or xpath queries. Other solution is to use Solr as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXSK2RvVJsk).You don't need solr but watch the video to get idea.